# How to reset git repo to a clean state as if I just cloned it?

Tags: git

Basically when fiddling with a git repo of a project, I got lost in what exactly is happening, why some files are the way they are and how it all ties together. I'd just like to reset the whole repo locally to a clean state as if I just cloned it from the remote branch - how would I go about it?

I've tried doing: `git reset --hard origin/develop` but it doesn't really help - I still have old versions of files in the project directories and yet `git pull` tells me everything's up to date - which it isn't.

How do I do it, then?

Comment: Remove the `.git` folder and start again using `git init` ?

Comment: Why not just delete the working directory and re-clone it?

Answer (score -1):

If you have not done any commits then you can just do `git stash`. Otherwise you will need to do `git reset --hard @{u}`